# Controlling two NICs with one driver

Tags: linux, networking, driver, linux-device-driver, nic

I'm currently trying to modify e1000e driver to use standard network adapters (82574L) in network with ring topology (I don't mean any specific ring topology). I want to do this at driver level (I'm still learning about drivers, mostly from "Linux Device Drivers").
So my question is:
Is it possible to control 2 network adapters with one driver? I mean, is it possible to write driver for "virtual adapter" which could control 2 physical adapters, and to make them to be seen as one device by system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and a lot of drivers actually do this. Usual approach is to create a "bus" driver, meaning that your driver will serve some kind of bus, for example, PCI. But no one stops you from creating your own virtual bus.

So that bus driver will be invoked for all devices that appears or disappears on your bus. When you get notification about device on your bus you will create and register structure for Linux kernel, e.g. `struct net_device` or more general `struct device`.

Actually you have a lot of options here as a device driver developer. You can create/register for each of the devices (like your e1000 driver), somehow group devices and represent lots of physical devices as single logical (RAID), wrap them to something very specific (device mapper) and so on.

Comment: Ask separate question. I don't understand what you mean.